Blender Not exporting vertex alpha into .glb
Blender Version: 4.1.1
When attempting to export vertex colour alpha for masking, it doesn't get exported at all.
RBG channels export correctly, but alpha is completely missing
This is not an issue on the import side, since reimporting it back into Blender yields identical results

Before and after exporting and importing (greenery visualises vertex alpha)


Have previously exported vertex alpha in 3.x Blender, so wonder what changed to break or make functionality less available

Alpha channel for vertex colors is definitely a part of the glTF 2.0 standard, however it is not supported in Blender's glTF exporter yet. Follow the issue on GitHub for updates.
